# Extract string in url after # in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Due to my current implementation of using QR Codes, I cannot change the request url. I need to be able to parse an address to get the string after the hash sign, i.e.:
    http://domain.com/#getthisstring
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this on the server side. URL fragment identifiers are not sent to the server.

You can however trap this value on the client side with JavaScript and send an Ajax request to the server passing the aforementioned value.

An impl in jQuery perchance?

```
$(function() {
   $.post('someRailsEndpoint', {hash: document.location.hash});
});
```

On the Rails end, you'd use `params[:hash]` to access this value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To clarify, the path of action is going to be: Scan QR code --> blackberry mobile browser. Is this a problem? My understanding is that blackberry's dont have javascript turned on by default?