# get access token from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can somebody tell me "How can I get an parameter from url?"

In my client application I send request to server with my client_id and after that server send me response with my "redirect_url", like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/orders/4#access_token=5756756856789579
```

How can I extract an "access_token" parameter and use them as an access token for next request?

Comment: are you sure that you want a hashtag "#" and not a ampersand "&" so you end up with `http://localhost:3000/orders/4&access_token=5756756856789579`

Comment: can you tell me how you are creating that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access access_token in javascript using window.location.hash. It is not accessible on server side.

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176206/extract-string-in-url-after-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thank you, Shishir!
But can you tell me why this metod return nil in view?
<%= @access_token.inspect %> is nil (

Comment: JS is working, in routes post '/orders/show'
And in orders controller in show action: @access_token = params[:access_token]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the link_to helper like this

```
= link_to order_path(@order, access_token: @access_token)
```

now in your controller you should be able to see

```
params[:access_token]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my question is closed. For access access_token i use jquery :)

**Thank you, Shishir!**

```
$(function() {
    var access_token = document.location.hash;
    alert(access_token);
});
```